# How to pass complex data from one fragment to another without using bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, parameter-passing

A guy posed me a question as to how to pass data which is non serializable from one fragment to another without using Bundle , I said one of the ways was to use GSON library , but he needed another way ? Any answers please .

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: Use EventBus(https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) directly object can be share between any of two classes just post a sticky event.

Comment: Pass the heavy Object itself by giving its reference. But personally Fragment should be independent with other fragments not unless it is a nested fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Android deverlopers page:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Ok .. i got the point .. but could there be more explanation to accept the answer

Comment: You have an activity and two fragments: fragment A and fragment B. 
In fragment A, you define an interface and you implement it in activity. 
In fragment A you call the interface method and activity will receive the event. Now the activity can delivery data to fragment B using the fragment's public methods.